# finding number of line segments a pt lies on

Tags: algorithm

Given n line segments and a pt. I want to find the line segments the pt lies on.A line segment is denoted by x[start] and x[ending]. All the line segments can be assumed to be on the x -axis.Also the line segments may be overlapping. Is there a better solution than O(n).
I think if the segments would have been not overlapping sorting and binary search would have done the trick.There are many pts and i want to find the numbers of pts on each line segment

Answer (score 1):

It can't be better than `O(n)`. You have to check every segment. Sorting is worse - `O(N log N)`.

Comment: i have edited the question.Suppose there are n pts.Is it possible to find the number of pts that lie on each line segment(suppose there are m) in less than O(n*m)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you ask this because there are multiple pt you wanna query.

Consider that all `n` segments contains pt, it can't be better than `O(n)` if you want to find out exactly which segments has contained pt.

However if you just want to count the number, you can use some data structures to optimize your queries. like `binary indexed tree` can allow you `O(nlog)` to prepare and `O(log)` for one query.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, by "All the line segments can be assumed to be on the x -axis." you mean to say that you have a set of (overlapping) intervals and query them with points, is that correct?

If so, I would propose the following approach:

1. Transform the input intervals into a new set of non-overlapping intervals with weights, where the weight of an interval is the number of original intervals that interval is in. For instance, if you have the input `{(0, 2), (1, 3)}`, transform this into `{(0, 1)=>1, (1, 2)=>2, (1, 3)=>1}`. I wrote [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16305338/2095090) a while ago on how to deal with overlapping intervals. Your question is different, but the approach is the same.
2. Build a [segment tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) on these new intervals to do the queries.

Given `n` intervals, you can do step one in `O(n log n)` time. You'll end up with `O(n)` new intervals, so building the segment tree takes `O(n log n)` time as well. Querying can then be done in `O(log n)` time.