# Exclude overlapping intervals with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have two lists of intervals. I would like to remove all ranges from list1 that already exist in list2.
Example:
List1:

> [(0,10),(15,20)]

List2:

> [(2,3),(5,6)]

Output:

> [(0,2),(3,5),(6,10),(15,20)]

Here was the same question asking how to do it in Java [Exclude overlapping intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304245/exclude-overlapping-intervals),
but I want to do it with numpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list1 = [(0,10),(15,20)]
list2 = [(2,3),(5,6)]

s = min(list1[0][0], list2[0][0])
e = max(list1[-1][-1], list2[-1][-1])
# by default no slot is in an interval (0)
arr = np.full((e - s + 3,), 0)
# mark intervals from list1
for a, b in list1:
    arr[a-s+1:b-s+1] = 1
# unmark intervals from list2
for a, b in list2:
    arr[a-s+1:b-s+1] = 0
# detect edges (start and end points)
starts = np.where((arr[1:] == 1) & (arr[:-1] == 0))[0] + s
ends = np.where((arr[:-1] == 1) & (arr[1:] == 0))[0] + s

print(list(zip(starts, ends)))
```

prints

```
[(0, 2), (3, 5), (6, 10), (15, 20)]
```

Note: this assumes each interval to have the smaller number first, each list to have the intervals ordered ascending and only integer entries.

Edit: To make this also work with non-integer entries, one can adapt the code as follows:

```
def f(list1, list2):
    # put all times in a single ordered list
    s1, e1 = zip(*list1)
    s2, e2 = zip(*list2)
    srtd = sorted(set(s1) | set(s2) | set(e1) | set(e2))
    arr = [np.nan] + srtd + [np.nan]
    # create a corresponding vector of 1s indicating incl. and 0s excl.
    idx = np.full((len(arr),), 0)
    for a, b in list1:
        idx[arr.index(a):arr.index(b)] = 1
    for a, b in list2:
        idx[arr.index(a):arr.index(b)] = 0
    # detect rising and falling edges
    idxs = (idx[1:-1] == 1) & (idx[:-2] == 0)
    idxe = (idx[1:-1] == 0) & (idx[:-2] == 1)
    # extract and pair start and end times of valid intervals
    arr = np.array(arr)
    starts = arr[1:-1][idxs]
    ends = arr[1:-1][idxe]
    return list(zip(starts, ends))

# example usage
print(f([[0.1,10],[15.5,20]], [[2,3.3],[5,6]]))
```

prints

```
[(0.1, 2.0), (3.3, 5.0), (6.0, 10.0), (15.5, 20.0)]
```

Comment: What if the intervals have non-integer entries? Any elegant way to do the same?

Comment: Note that this requires a ton of memory (and time) to compute `f([(0,10**20)], [(2, 3)]`.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I assume you refer to the first code snippet and not `f`, because, `f([(0,10**20)], [(2, 3)]` definitely does not require a ton of memory or runtime. But there you are totally right, thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @MichaelHodel is the last  `+ [np.nan]` necessary in arr? I don' t see it being accessed at any point. want to make sure im not missing something

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer for non-integer entries. Works. Any more elegant way to do it?

```
def locateInIntervals(list1, x):
    """
    find the interval in list1 x belongs to, and the interval before x
    assume list1 is sorted and contains intervals that do not overlap
    return: [ibefore, i_in]
    """
    starts = [x[0] for x in list1]
    if x < starts[0]:
        return [-42, -42] # x lies before the first interval
    else:
        indx = np.where(x >= np.array(starts))[0][-1]
        if x < list1[indx][1]:
            if indx==0: return [-42, indx] # x in list1[0]
            else: return [indx-1, indx] # x in list1[indx] for indx>0
        else: return [indx, -42] # x follows list1[indx] but not in any interval

def excludeIntervals(list1, list2):
    """
    exclude intervals in list2 from list1.
    assume intervals do not overlap 
    """
    list1 = [list(interval) for interval in list1]
    list2 = [list(interval) for interval in list2]
    list1.sort()
    list2.sort()
    res = list1
    for interval in list2:
        ind_start_before, ind_start = locateInIntervals(res, interval[0])
        ind_end_before, ind_end = locateInIntervals(res, interval[1])
        if ((ind_start_before < 0) & (ind_start < 0) & (ind_end >= 0)):
            res[ind_end] = [interval[1], res[ind_end][1]]
            for i in range(ind_end): del res[I]
        elif ((ind_start_before < 0) & (ind_start < 0) & (ind_end_before >= 0) & (ind_end < 0)):
            for i in range(ind_end_before+1): del res[I]
        elif ((ind_start >= 0) & (ind_end >= 0)):
            if ind_start==ind_end:
                res.insert(ind_start+1, [interval[1], res[ind_end][1]])
                res[ind_start] = [res[ind_start][0], interval[0]]
            else:
                res[ind_start] = [res[ind_start][0], interval[0]]
                res[ind_end] = [interval[1], res[ind_end][1]]
        elif ((ind_start >= 0) & (ind_end_before >= 0) & (ind_end < 0)): 
            res[ind_start] = [res[ind_start][0], interval[0]]
            for i in range(ind_start+1, ind_end_before+1): del res[I]
        elif ((ind_start_before >= 0) & (ind_start < 0) & (ind_end >= 0)):
            res[ind_end] = [interval[1], res[ind_end][1]]
            for i in range(ind_start_before+1, ind_end): del res[I]
        elif ((ind_start_before >= 0) & (ind_start < 0) & (ind_end < 0)):
            for i in range(ind_start_before+1, ind_end_before+1): del res[I]
    return res
```

excludeIntervals([[0.1,10],[15.5,20]], [[2,3.3],[5,6]])

returns [[0.1, 2], [3.3, 5], [6, 10], [15.5, 20]]

Comment: Adapted my answer to also work with non-integer entries (but with a similar procedure as for integer entries)